# How can I improve the load time and layout of my icon images?

Tags: html, css, positioning

My web site has code like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a class='disabled' ><img src='../../Content/Icons/home.png' />Home</a></li>
<li><a href='xx'  title='xx'><img src='../../Content/Icons/xx.png' />xx</a></li>
<li><a href='yy'  title='yy'><img src='../../Content/Icons/yy.png' />yy</a></li>
</ul>
```

There are two problems.

1) I'd like to combine my images into one larger image file containing multiple images. I thought about using background BUT my  sits on a DIV with a gradient background so I don't think I am not sure if it's possible. Note that my icons have a transparent background.
2) When the page displays there's a delay while the images load. After they have loaded them my DIVs shift slightly in position.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could do here. What I do need is for the icon positioning to be correct. Right now it looks like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x               x
x Icon     Home x
x               x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Hope someone can help with suggestions/hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, I'm not sure what you mean by combining them into a file with multiple images. You can combine them into a single image file, or they can be separate images, like they are now. I'm not sure what benefit you seek from having them in a single file. Modern browsers are pretty smart and you won't shave more than a few milliseconds off from doing it this way.

The second issue is the browser incorrectly guessing the images size on the first render. Check out [W3C's documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) for the img tag. Say, your image is 25px by 25px. You could do something like:

```
<img src='../../Content/Icons/xx.png' width="25" height="25" />
```

That way the browser knows ahead of time what space the image will take once it's available.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I will implement width and height. Should be easy as they are all the same size. You are correct. What I would like to do is to combine them into one file with multiple images if possible.